# Creating Emoji-like keyboard using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create a custom on-screen keyboard for my website using JavaScript. So far I have the keys have ASCII values associated with them like: { value: 71 },{ value: 72 },{ value: 74 }, etc. This shows the letter on the key seen by the user and echoes on the screen when the user clicks it.I have associated JavaScript functions with each key, which converts the keystroke into a string.

My question is how can I replace text on the key visible to the user with a smiley or a emoji-like graphic?:

Answer (score 0):

What you could try is using `document.createElement("img");`
This creates a dynamic element, based on what is found in either a database, or after user-inputs like a button or textfield.

I am not sure what the structure of your keyboard looks like though, could you provide some HTML / JavaScript code of how you coded it?

For more information about `createElement`, go to: [W3 IMG (createElement)](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_image.asp)